# C# Do while loop

Tags: c#, loops, messagebox, do-while

I'm new to programming. I want to create a program that adds 10 integers and will display a message box indicating how many correct answers i got. I just used 1 label box and a button. Here's the code I used. It's working perfectly until the message box shows me that I only got 1 correct answer. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
    }
    int a;
    int b; 
    string sagot;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        do
        {
            a = i + i;
            label1.Text = i.ToString() + " + " + i.ToString() + "=";
            sagot = Interaction.InputBox("Please type your answer:");
            i++;

        } while (i <= 10);

        {
            if (a == Convert.ToInt32(sagot))
                    {
                    b++;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Number of correct answers: " + b.ToString());
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: messed up code, please clean up it...

Comment: and also a very confused programmer

Comment: It's like a crazy bracket explosion......

Comment: I hate to laugh but I had some fun trying to figure out what the heck your intention is with this code.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets look at your code:

```
int a; 
int b;  
string sagot; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int i = 1; 
    do 
    { 
        a = i + i; 
        label1.Text = i.ToString() + " + " + i.ToString() + "="; 
        sagot = Interaction.InputBox("Please type your answer:"); 
        i++; 

    } while (i <= 10); 

    { 
        if (a == Convert.ToInt32(sagot)) 
                { 
                b++; 
                } 
            } 
            MessageBox.Show("Number of correct answers: " + b.ToString()); 
        } 
    } 
    }
```

So.

You start at 1, and a= i*2, you ask them to enter i+i. you get their response, and increment i.

First issue is here.. You arent testing their response!! Once you go round the loop again, a and "sagot" is no longer remembered to test for later, so if you dont test now.. its gone.

Once you do that once i=10 it will come out the loop ..

So..

Now you ask it, if a is the same as the answer they gave, add one to b

well you only do that once.. and it only applies to the last answer..

Therefore, yes, you will get a score of 1 out of 10.....

You have a few to many braces. However..

So, having told you where you went wrong.. and no Im not going to point out any issues such as if you write "FRED" as an answer.. your app will barf..

Heres your code shuffled to get what you meant it to do - but in your way of doing it - not mine.

```
int a; 
int b;  
string sagot; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int i = 1; 
    do 
    { 
        a = i + i; 
        label1.Text = i.ToString() + " + " + i.ToString() + "="; 
        sagot = Interaction.InputBox("Please type your answer:"); 
        i++; 
             if (a == Convert.ToInt32(sagot)) 
                { 
                b++; 
                } 
    } while (i <= 10); 

            MessageBox.Show("Number of correct answers: " + b.ToString());
```

Comment: +1 for "but in your way of doing it - not mine"  :-)

Comment: I didnt wanna confuse the poor guy by blowing away all his code, and handing him something completely different.. just shuffled it round todo what he meant.. I think if you're new enough to be struggling you are new enough that changing it all would confuse you!

Comment: @BugFinder - a very gentle, supportive answer

Comment: @BugFinder Totally agree. I just love how you phrased that for the rest of us.

Comment: @BugFinder thank you for response. it's working properly now. :)

Comment: Do you understand though why yours didnt work to start with, and why the changed code does?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, I do. I'm sorry for not being able to see what I did wrong and thanks again for the answer :-)

Comment: Thats the important bit, is that you can see why it didnt work.. Otherwise, having the answer doesnt help you learn for next time :) enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're doing the `b++` AFTER the loop, so it'll only get executed once. Try moving it inside the loop.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        a = i + i;
        label1.Text = i.ToString() + " + " + i.ToString() + "=";
        sagot = Interaction.InputBox("Please type your answer:");
        i++;
        if (a == Convert.ToInt32(sagot))
        {
            b++;
        }

    } while (i <= 10);

    MessageBox.Show("Number of correct answers: " + b.ToString());
}
```

Also, as a side note, you should work on cleaning up your code a little. Specifically your use of brackets. You don't wanna use brackets unless you're enclosing statements. Typical uses would be method bodies, loops, conditionals, `using` statements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate your answer during the loop, like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    int b = 0;
    do
    {
        a = i + i;
        label1.Text = i.ToString() + " + " + i.ToString() + "=";
        sagot = Interaction.InputBox("Please type your answer:");
        i++;

        if (a == Convert.ToInt32(sagot))
        {
            b++;
        }

    } while (i <= 10);

    MessageBox.Show("Number of correct answers: " + b.ToString());
}
```